# Dynamically created popover with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am normally a backend dev; but for this I know I am getting caught out by not working within the how the web browser works.

I left the JavaScript alert in there for ease of use. depending on which button you clicked in the popover it should popup and say leave-X or office-x where X is the ID of the  which the button was a part of.

But they all say "leave-1" or "office-1" regardless of which field I choose. I know I am pulling the correct data from the correct field as changing "1" to say "foo" it will display office-foo.

I would rather not have a separate bespoke popover for each table-cell as that would be hundreds of entries in the final product.

My basic 2x2 table & jQuery/bootstrap code:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-placement="bottom" tabindex=-1 data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body" id="1" class="td-Office">1</td>
      <td data-placement="bottom" tabindex=-1 data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body" id="2" class="td-Office">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-placement="bottom" tabindex=-1 data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body" id="3" class="td-Office">3</td>
      <td data-placement="bottom" tabindex=-1 data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body" id="4" class="td-Office">4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>




var parentClass = $("[data-toggle=popover]").attr('id');
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({html: true, content: `<div id="popover-content">
    <button id="office-`+ parentClass +`" class="btn btn-sm btn-Office" onclick="toggleTD(this);">Office</button>
    <button id="leave-`+ parentClass +`" class="btn btn-sm btn-Leave" onclick="toggleTD(this);">Leave</button>
  </div>`});

$('.popover-dismiss').popover({
  trigger: 'focus'
}) 
function toggleTD(elm) {
    alert(elm.id);
}
```

Comment: Try playing with this https://jsfiddle.net/J7nDz/48/ and see if any light bulbs turn on.

Comment: Does this work for you?  https://jsfiddle.net/J7nDz/48/

Comment: That looks like a brute force method i'd rather not do. As mentioned it'll eventually need hundreds of popovers. I know there is a solution somwhere in this: https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Material-Design-Context-Menu-jQuery-3Dot-Context-Menu.html. but i can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is that parentClass value is always "1";

If you want to use the button id, replace the content with a function, and use this.id:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
   html: true, 
   content: function() { 
      return `<div id="popover-content">
               <button id="office-`+ this.id +`" class="btn btn-sm btn-Office" onclick="toggleTD(this);">Office</button>
               <button id="leave-`+ this.id +`" class="btn btn-sm btn-Leave" onclick="toggleTD(this);">Leave</button>
            </div>`
   }
 });
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew it was gonna be something simple and this fixed it

Comment: happy to help! ;)